# count number of digits after decimal point in Python

Tags: python, floating-point

```
def ndigits(n):
    y=n-int(n)
    print(y)
    #y = 0.45600000000000307 ! it should be 0.456

    after=0
    while(y!=0):
        #print(y)
        y=y*10
        y=y-int(y)
        after +=1
    print("number of digits after decimal point=",after)


ndigits(123.456)
```

Result: 
the number of digits after decimal point= 46
it should be 3!

Comment: def ndigits(n):
   y = str(n)
   print("number of digits after decimal point = ", len(y.split('.')[1]))
ndigits(123.456)

Comment: Just replace `while (y != 0)` by `while (y > 1e-10)`. Before the while-loop, you should add 1e-11 to n, to also capture the case when y would be represented as 123.455999999999999

Comment: Note that floating point math has about 15 decimal digits of precision, but is internally represented in binary